# Vampire's skin color and sunlight resistance

Tags: vampires, sunlight

Watching this [TED talk](https://www.ted.com/talks/nina_jablonski_breaks_the_illusion_of_skin_color?language=en) got me thinking about skin color and consequent "affinities" for different amounts of sunlight. It does make some sense, especially when we talk about skin cancer.

However, the true substance of my question relates to vampires. As you can guess from the title, I want to ask: Is a vampire's resistance to sunlight directly related to his/her skin color? If there are no such examples, would you consider this as a worldbuilding factor?

I have a couple of theories, one about the amount of UV light from the sun (which could mean that the theory has substance), the other about the "mythical value" (I can't remember the related philosophical name for it) of "sunlight" as possessing holy power -- in which case skin color shouldn't have an effect, but neither would artificial sunlight / UV blasts.

Are there any examples of this theory having been used in literature or other popular media?

Answer (score 1):

The idea that vampires need resistance from sunlight at all is apparently relatively new.  From TV tropes [Daywalking Vampire](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/DaywalkingVampire):

> This was in fact the standard in traditional Vampire lore and early
>   Vampire fiction. Lord Ruthven, Varney the Vampire, Carmilla and
>   Dracula could all prance around in broad daylight, and while some of
>   these might be accustomed to sleeping during the day, daylight in
>   itself was no danger to them. The trope that daylight is lethal to
>   vampires came into being only with movies, specifically with 1922's
>   Dracula adaptation Nosferatu.

All Daywalkers that I am aware of in recent times rely on some magical process to acquire or otherwise define their daywalking abilities.  However, there's no reason you couldn't elect to associate it with UV light, which would create an easy reason why skin pigmentation matters.  Or you could just associate it directly with skin pigmentation!  It's your world!  Whatever makes your world feel like a living breathing world is the right way to go!

Comment: Thanks for the link to that page! I was always rather suspicious of how many weaknesses vampires had. Knowing that the addition of sunlight was by way of Nosferatu and not in the "original" template is rather eye-opening.